# Error while creating Template Building Block with core service

Tags: core-service, templating

We are currently working in Java to export data from a tridion environment, creating files like template.tctcmp and template.dwt. When importing these files back into tridion with the core service, no problem arises except, when trying to import the dreamweaver file I get 2 ICoreServiceSaveCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage errors:

> "'tcdl' is an undeclared prefix. Line 3, position 8."

and

> "Unable to parse compound template content"

Of course there is a  tag in the dreamweaver template, but how would you go on in to importing the template back into tridion?

The current code I am using:

```
template = (TemplateData) endpoint.getDefaultData(ItemType.TEMPLATE_BUILDING_BLOCK, folderUri);
template.getTitle().setValue(filename);
template.setContent(objectFactory.createTemplateDataContent(content);
this.endpoint.save(template, null);
```

Where content is the text from the dwt file.

Comment: Dare I ask why are you doing this instead of using Content Porter?

Comment: @NunoLinhares sure, because that thing doesn't work properly in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, or atleast not the way we would like it to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem might be that you are not setting `TemplateType` property. Check what is your `TemplateType`, or set it to `DreamweaverTemplate`